# mvn package trying to get arrtifact as mar instead of jar

Tags: maven, jar, package, dependencies

I am trying to build a code, in one of the dependecnies there is a transitive dependecy with packaging type mar.
when I am trying to build my code, it is trying to get the artifact form the repository as mar instead of jar (eg: Downloading from my-artifacts: http:myrepo/my-artifacts/x/y/z/artifact/1.0/artifact-1.0.mar )
and on myrepo the artifact is available but as jar.
so mvn should be trying to download this artifact as jar not as mar, however it is acting differently.
Any idea what is causing this? and how to enforce maven to try to download the dependency as jar?

Comment: Your Pom.xml tells it to. Maven does not know what is in the repository

Comment: I mean in he reposior these is artifact-1.0.jar, but when I'm building my code, mvn is trying to pull the artifact as artifact-1.0.mar not as artifact-1.0.jar.